# Changing 7 day calendar to 5 day

Tags: javascript, html, date, calendar

I'm currently working on a 7 day calendar (sun-sat) which works great but I was looking to add an option to change it to a 5 day calendar (mon-fri). I was hoping I could just change the existing code to display my calendar. Any ideas how I would go about this?

**Calendar**

```
calendarString = '';
calendarString += '<table width="100%" height="425" data-role="table" border="1" bordercolor="#c0c0c0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
    calendarString += '<tr>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sun<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Mon<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Tue<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Wed<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Thu<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Fri<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sat<\/td>';
    calendarString += '<\/tr>';

    thisDate == 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
        {
            calendarString += '<tr>';
            for (var x = 1; x <= 7; x++) 
                {
                    daycounter = (thisDate - firstDay)+1;
                    thisDate++;
                    if ((daycounter > numbDays) || (daycounter < 1)) 
                        {
                            calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#888888\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">&nbsp;<\/td>';
                        } 
                    else 
                        {
                            if (checkevents(daycounter,monthNum,yearNum,i,x) || ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum)))
                                {
                                    if ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum)) 
                                        {
                                            tempweek = i;
                                            tempdayofweek = x;
                                            calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#AAFFAA\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" onClick=showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')>' + daycounter + '<\/td>';
                                        }
                                else    
                                    {
                                    calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFC8\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" onClick=showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')>' + daycounter + '<div id="amountevent" style="padding-left:5px;max-height:8px; height:8px; width:30px; max-width:30px;white-space: nowrap;">' + displayeventnumber(daycounter, monthNum, yearNum) + '</div><\/td>';


                                    }
                            } 
                            else 
                                {
                                    calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#f9f9f9\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">' + daycounter + '<\/td>';         
                                }
                        }
                }
            calendarString += '<\/tr>';
        }
    calendarString += '<\/table>';
    var object=document.getElementById('calendar');
    object.innerHTML= calendarString;
    thisDate = 1;
```

Comment: Why not add a `weekend` class to their "rows", then you could `hide` or `show` by targeting the class.

Comment: How would i go about this, i would need to detect a way for the function to know what day it is for that to happen ?

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to have the exact same html for both styles, but dynamically hide sunday-saturday columns if the user selects a five-day calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sun<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sat<\/td>';
```

Change

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 7; x++)
```

to

```
for (var x = 2; x <= 6; x++)
```

Comment: that was my first attempted myself, this month it shows Tuesday the 4th of feb as the 1st of feb.